# duply/duplicity -- where should I save profile data?

Tags: amazon-s3, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I am trying to set up a backup to Amazon S3 servers using duply, which is a front-end for duplicity.

When I create a duply profile, this message is returned:

```
IMPORTANT:
Copy the _whole_ profile folder after the first backup to a safe place.
It contains everything needed to restore your backups. You will need 
it if you have to restore the backup from another system (e.g. after a 
system crash). Keep access to these files restricted as they contain 
_all_ informations (gpg data, ftp data) to access and modify your backups.

Repeat this step after _all_ configuration changes. Some configuration 
options are crucial for restoration.
```

What is a reasonable way to go about doing this?

My purpose for setting up an encrypted off-site backup is that I don't want to lose all my data if there is physical damage (fire, etc.) to my home.

So, saving this information in a thumb drive doesn't seem like a good idea, since the thumb drive would also be destroyed in such an event.

Saving this information on the Amazon S3 server itself seems like it would  completely compromise the encryption.

If not these two options, where does one save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about tar'ing the profile folder and encrypt it with gpg (long symmetric passphrase or against your personal private key) and saving it off-site?

of course you can use anything else that can securely encrypt archives/files.

..ede/duply.net

PS: never use thumbdrives/flash based memory for archiving purposes. when not connected regularly to power they lose memory cell content because it is not refreshed.

Comment: This is grossly incorrect information about flash memory. It is completely incorrect that flash drives and flash memory needs to be regularly to powered, that is not how flash memory works. Flash memory has no real aging issue, stored memory has a very long retention period, it is one of the best ways to store data long-term, better than tape (requires periodic re-spooling), HDs (which must be periodic spun up), Writable CDs that have essentially a 10 year lifetime. Further there is no refresh cycles like dynamic RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Save it on several flash drives, put one in a bank safe deposit vault, they are not expensive.